# Define one table for each type of relationship that requires approval vs defining one generic table to fit all

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I am designing a database for an application in mysql 5.5 that has a Many-to-Many relationship between a User table and a Business table as follows:

```
user
----
user_id (PK)

handle

email

password

password_salt

created_at

updated_at


business
--------
business_id (PK)

business_name

website

created_at

updated_at

updated_by
```

For which I have defined the following bridge table

```
user_business_relationship
--------------------------
user_id (FK) (PF)

business_id (FK) (PF)
```

However, the business requires approval before a user is associated to a business and the relationship is logged in the user_business_relationship table

Thus, I have defined the following approver table

```
(option 1)
--------

user_business_relationship_approver
-----------------------------------
user_id (FK) (PF)

business_id (FK) (PF)

approver_id (FK) (PF)

status |requested|approved|rejected|

updated_at
```

### My question is the following:

I know that as I expand my database design I will have other types of situations where I will need to use the same approval workflow that will require another table such as:

```
user_promotions_relationship_approver
-------------------------------------

and so on
```

So, would you recommend that I define separate approver tables for each type of relationship or is it better to only define one generic approver table for any type of relationship that requires approval?

```
(option 2)
----------

relationship_approver
---------------------
requestor_id |user_id| (PK) (PF)

request_id |business_id|promotion_id|etc| (PK) (PF)

approver_id (PF) (PF)

request_type

status

updated_at

updated_by
```

I will also appreciate any other feedback regarding my current design. Thank you

Comment: Why use a seperate table? Just use the approval table.

Comment: separate tables are good for scalability.  It sounds like this will grow, and for normalization purposes, it's cleaner to keep items like approver separate.  I'd keep type on the last table (unless you want a control table;  I'm big on those, quite simply because poor authority control can create a huge mess, especially for large amounts of data.  Look at the Library of Congress records if you want confirmation of that.)

Comment: incidentally, I like this approach.  it's clean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple approvers, and need them associated with multiple transactions, the approach that you are using is good.

As you are concerned with scalability, I would use a combination of option 1 and 2.

In other words,  I would use this approach:

```
user_business_relationship_approver

user_id (FK) (PF)
business_id (FK) (PF)
approver_id (FK) (PF)
status |requested|approved|rejected|
updated_at
```

but also add in this field

```
request_type
```

In fact it might be a good idea to have a control table to manage the types (this is my personal choice in these cases)

so you would have a table like so:

```
request_type
type_id (PK)
type_name
```

and then `type_id` would also live on `user_business_relationship_approver` as an `FK`

This way if you have a new request type, you can simply add it to the `request_type` table, and it will become an option to choose for the other table.

Comment: If the only data "request_type" holds is it's name, and if it doesn't need to be constantly updated, you can use an ENUM type and avoid the "request_type" table.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply define an aditional status field in the main relationship table:

```
user_business_relationship

user_id (FK) (PF)
business_id (FK) (PF)
status |requested|approved|rejected|
```

If you do that, you don't need any extra tables to deal with the approval. You can also add as many extra fields you may need, to identify the requester, the approver, date of request, date of approval, and so on.

Comment: adding extra fields whenever you need one fails a simple normalization test.

Comment: I am concerned with scalability (as we all are :)) and as nomistic stated this way it is normalized. But, if you have an argument against this approach I'd love to hear it. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: I'm used to deal with big databases, and I try to use simple and manageable solutions to my problems. I'm always trying to avoid unnecessary tables when it doesn't sacrifice performance or easy management.